# database design -create and query a table with an extra unique key from 2 fields

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have a table of security prices with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `security_prices` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `price_date` date NOT NULL,
  `ticker` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

The `id` is just there to be the primary key and serves no other purpose. However, as may be obvious, although one can have many records with the same `ticker` and you can also have many records with the same `price_date`, no two records should have the same `ticker` and `price_date` at the same time.

How would I define a unique constraint on these two fields and what is the best way to INSERT in to the database whilst handling any integrity violation?

I am currently using MySQL with phpmyadmin.

Comment: make ticker and price_date as composite primary keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is ::

```
ALTER TABLE `security_prices`ADD UNIQUE (ticker, price_date);
```

But before this you need to be sure for the combination of the two columns doesnt have a duplicate row.

Comment: OK, how would I then UPDATE the table. I seem to think you can skip the insert or overwrite when a violation is encountered

Comment: @harryg
Yes, if there is a violation of the unique constraint, the db will trigger an error, you need to handle the same in your application code, unique constraint will ensure that no rows will be inserted through any mean